# Fetch sql query with Machine Name

Tags: oracle

I want to fetch sql query with machine name where sql query has been run and machine name can belong's to any user. Please guide how is it possible to get that by joing tables like DBA_hist_sql or any other table.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest such variant

```
select 
    s.sql_id,
    s.sql_text,
    d.machine
from 
    v$sql s,
    dba_hist_active_sess_history d
where
    d.sql_id = s.sql_id
```

Maybe there is better variant or more related to your question. I hope it wil be helpful for you.

I let you links on documentation of these views.

[DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3125.htm#REFRN23400)

[V$SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246)

Answer (score 0):

You can join `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` and `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` , as long as the sql has been captured in the workload repository.

In the `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` you have the field `MACHINE`, where you got the value of `SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','host')` .

You can join both views by sql_id.

However, the query will not be registered on the workload repository if it's not meaningful. You can modify this behaviour by changing settings of `AWR` using  `DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.MODIFY_SNAPSHOT_SETTINGS`

An example

```
    select 
    distinct s.sql_id,
    s.sql_text,
    d.machine ,
    u.username ,
    d.program
from 
    gv$sql s inner join dba_hist_active_sess_history d  
     on (  d.sql_id = s.sql_id  and S.INST_ID = D.INSTANCE_NUMBER )
                inner join  dba_users u on (  D.USER_ID = U.USER_ID  )
where
     u.username = '&1' 
     S.SQL_ID = '&2' 
 order by D.SAMPLE_TIME desc
```

You can apply the filter by username or sql_id, or both. keep in mind that the field USERNAME will show you the Oracle user who executed the query, not the operating system user behind that connection.

Comment: In sql history update command is getting shown however if  i do select * from v$sql or dba_hist_sqltext then not able to see that update command of that particular time..

Comment: can you post your query in the question ?

Comment: suggestion: if the update is getting you problems, you might want to apply the hint `monitoring`. that will force Oracle to register the query no matter what is significant or not

Comment: @JaspreetSingh, I post a query. let me know any doubt you might have. Really appreciated if you upvote the answer